# Error : "Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames" in RStudio while exporting data to Excel Sheet

Tags: r, writexl

```
# ----
setwd("F:/Business Analytics/Shares Monitor")

getSymbols("TATACONSUM.NS", src="yahoo")

library("writexl")
write_xlsx("TATACONSUM.NS","F:/Business Analytics/Shares Monitor//Stock_TATACONSUM-NS.xlsx")

# ----
```

I have written the above code to download the shares information data of a particular company and export it into Excel Sheet. When I run this script. it is creating the expected result and it is  shows the Data in RStudio Environment. But it shows following error and does not export it into excel sheet :

```
Error in write_xlsx("TATACONSUM.NS", "F:/Business Analytics/Shares Monitor//Stock_TATACONSUM-NS.xlsx") : 
  Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
```

Could someone please tell me what am I missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to it. Instead of using `write_xlsx()` Function, I used `write.zoo()` Function and it is working now.

```
#----
setwd("F:/Business Analytics/Shares Monitor")

getSymbols("TATACONSUM.NS", src="yahoo")
write.zoo(TATACONSUM.NS, file = "F:/Business Analytics/Shares Monitor//Stock_TATACONSUM-NS.csv", sep = ",")

#----
```